# problem with mocking useAppSelector for testing with Jest, RTL, Redux Toolkit, React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit

I have react redux toolkit installed and I've added jest instead of vitest for testing.

I want to test that modal window is rendered in App component, if isOpen flag is true. I'm mocking only the part of the store that I need. Not the whole store.

App Component

```
function App() {
  const { isOpen: isPostModalWindowOpen } = useAppSelector(selectPostModal)

  return (
    <div className="app-container" id="app-container">
      {isPostModalWindowOpen && <PostModalWindow />}
      <Posts />
      <PageLoader />
      <Alert />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

test file

```
import App from "../App"
import { PostModalWindow } from "../components/PostModalWindow/PostModalWindow"
import { selectPostModal } from "../redux/postModal"
import { Alert } from "../components/Alert/Alert"
import { PageLoader } from "../components/PageLoader/PageLoader"
import { Posts } from "../components/Posts/Posts"

import { useAppSelector } from "../redux/hooks"
import { render } from "@testing-library/react"
import { RootState } from "../redux/store"
import { clone } from "ramda"

jest.mock("../App", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("../App"),
  App: jest.fn(),
}))
jest.mock("../components/PostModalWindow/PostModalWindow", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("../components/PostModalWindow/PostModalWindow"),
  PostModalWindow: jest.fn(),
}))
jest.mock("../redux/hooks", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("../redux/hooks"),
  useAppSelector: jest.fn(),
}))
jest.mock("../redux/postModal", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("../redux/postModal"),
  selectPostModal: jest.fn(),
}))
jest.mock("../components/Alert/Alert", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("../components/Alert/Alert"),
  Alert: jest.fn(),
}))
jest.mock("../components/PageLoader/PageLoader", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("../components/PageLoader/PageLoader"),
  PageLoader: jest.fn(),
}))
jest.mock("../components/Posts/Posts", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("../components/Posts/Posts"),
  Posts: jest.fn(),
}))

describe("Test <App />", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()

    const initialState = {
      postModal: {
        isOpen: true,
      },
    } as RootState
    let currentState: RootState

    currentState = clone(initialState)

    jest.mocked(useAppSelector).mockImplementation((fn) => fn(currentState))
  })

  it("show modal window if isOpen is true", () => {
    const { container } = render(<App />)
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

how to fix this test error:
[TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isOpen' of '(0 , hooks_1.useAppSelector)(...)' as it is undefined.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wlWo.png)

I console.logged current state inside `jest.mocked(useAppSelector).mockImplementation((fn) => fn(currentState))` and it's returning `postModal: {isOpen: true}` so I don't know why it's saying that it's undefined.

Comment: Because you mocked the `selectPostModal` selector, it will return `undefined`.  Don't mock the selector function.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by realizing two mistakes in my testing approach.

Firstly, I wrongly attempted to mock the App component. Since we are testing the App component itself, there's no need to mock it. Mocking it can interfere with the actual testing process.

Secondly, I mishandled the mocking of selectPostModal. Instead of providing a value, I was trying to create a mock.

```
import App from "../App"
import { PostModalWindow } from "../components/PostModalWindow/PostModalWindow"
import { useAppSelector } from "../redux/hooks"
import { Alert } from "../components/Alert/Alert"
import { PageLoader } from "../components/PageLoader/PageLoader"
import { Posts } from "../components/Posts/Posts"

import { render } from "@testing-library/react"
import { RootState } from "../redux/store"
import { clone } from "ramda"

jest.mock("../components/PostModalWindow/PostModalWindow", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("../components/PostModalWindow/PostModalWindow"),
  PostModalWindow: jest.fn(),
}))
jest.mock("../redux/hooks", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("../redux/hooks"),
  useAppSelector: jest.fn(),
}))
jest.mock("../components/Alert/Alert", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("../components/Alert/Alert"),
  Alert: jest.fn(),
}))
jest.mock("../components/PageLoader/PageLoader", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("../components/PageLoader/PageLoader"),
  PageLoader: jest.fn(),
}))
jest.mock("../components/Posts/Posts", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("../components/Posts/Posts"),
  Posts: jest.fn(),
}))

describe("Test <App />", () => {
  const initialState = {
    postModal: {
      isOpen: true,
    },
  } as RootState
  let currentState: RootState

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()

    currentState = clone(initialState)

    jest.mocked(useAppSelector).mockImplementation((fn) => fn(currentState))
    jest
      .mocked(PostModalWindow)
      .mockImplementation(() => <div>mockedPostModalWindow</div>)
    jest.mocked(Posts).mockImplementation(() => <div>mockedPosts</div>)
    jest
      .mocked(PageLoader)
      .mockImplementation(() => <div>mockedPageLoader</div>)
    jest.mocked(Alert).mockImplementation(() => <div>mockedAlert</div>)
  })

  it("show modal window if isOpen is true", () => {
    const { container } = render(<App />)
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot()
  })

  it("Don't show modal window if isOpen is false", () => {
    currentState.postModal.isOpen = false

    const { container } = render(<App />)
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```